# Center Text in Middle of Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly position text in the middle of an image. I managed to get it to center but just on the very top of the image and not dead on middle.

```css
#ImageMain {
  background-image: url(C:/Users/Gabriel/Downloads/bg.jpg);
  width: 80%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#TextMain h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageMain">
  <div id="TextMain">

    <h1>Shop our Whole Selection</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `flex`property in css:

```css
#ImageMain {
background:#eee;
width: 80%;
height: 700px;
position: relative;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}

#TextMain h1 {
font-size: 100px;
font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageMain">
<div id="TextMain">

<h1>Shop our Whole Selection</h1>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple flexbox tweak on `#ImageMain` for vertical centering & `text-align` on the `h1` for horizontal centering (placehold.it image was used as demo):

```css
#ImageMain {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/500x500);
  width: 80%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
  /* new */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* end new */
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#TextMain h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  /* new */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageMain">
  <div id="TextMain">
    <h1>Shop our Whole Selection</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap up the text in div block

```
 <div name="text_main"><p>text</p></div>


  //apply css properties...
 //adjust position by applying margin-top and margin-bottom
 // then position the element by
  float:center //and try to make positon:fixed
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertically centering content in HTML is still a pita.

```css
#TextMain {
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 20em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
    border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="ImageMain">
<div id="TextMain">

<h1>Shop our Whole Selection</h1>

</div>
</div>
```

This is just one of many ways of doing it. This one doesn't use any tricks or workarounds or vendor specific instructions. It should just work everywhere.